# Some pink blood then stop, do i have to ghusl?

Tags: menses, maliki

Asslamualaikum

I am a sister. Last night I had some pink blood, and today nothing. dhuhr time has come :(
I'm expecting menstruation within the next 7 days, so this could have been a start, or could be after a week, Allah knows.

Do I do wudhu and pray? or do I have to ghusl, or do I keep waiting?

I am following Maliki school.

Hope you can help insha allah. Please answer even after the event in case it happens again.

jazakallah very much!

Comment: Walaikum-Asalaam , Sister you should take advice from some Mufti (Islamic Scholar) or read a Fatawa book related to Women Issues ,it will be hard to find answers related to specfic issues ,people who answer are not scholars they are just normal Muslim having little knowledge and some times you may even get reply from a non-Muslim ,so do some effort and seek Scholar advice (Fatawa website ,Book , Visit Mosque near you)

Comment: Wa'alikum as-salaam, please clarify if you want a general answer or one specifically addressing this issue from the Maliki madhab.

Answer (score 2):

According to the fatwa team at Islamweb.net, this blood is considered by Imam Malik to be a period.  Therefore you mustn't pray or touch the *Mushaf* or anything until you get *tuhur*.

Other scholars only consider it a period if it lasts for more than a day and night, otherwise it is not.

If you know Arabic, you can read the following *fatawa* (both from Islamweb.net) which describe the ruling in greater detail:

- [حكم من نزل منها قطرات دم قبل موعد دورتها بأسبوع](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=78228)
- [هل قطرة الدم الواحدة تعد حيضا؟](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=A&Id=32684)