# Can a female pray regular salah if she has been diagnosed with PCOS?

Tags: salat, menses

I have [PCOS](https://www.healthline.com/health/polycystic-ovary-disease) and my monthly cycles are not regular. Sometimes there is also spotting which lasts for weeks.

**Am I allowed to offer salah?**

Comment: Salah is a duty on every Muslim with a few exceptions that might be for the whole life time or temporary (coma, mental illness, menses etc.). A regular menses is among the temporary exceptions, if the menses becomes irregular then a woman must pray scholars might have different views on that, at least in matters of menses the maliki school of fiqh has some different opinion see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7114/some-pink-blood-then-stop-do-i-have-to-ghusl).

Comment: So you mean i can pray but still need to confirm? @Medi1Saif

Comment: Maybe [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48386/periods-of-two-weeks-duration) is helpful and basically covering your inquiry else let me know if not, else you may refer to [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40872/i-have-an-period-where-the-blood-comes-in-small-amounts-is-it-valid-for-me-to-f) for distinguishing a regular menses from an irregular one.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Okay so it seems i cannot pray. Thank you for your help brother. Assalamu alaikum

Comment: Note by regular menses I mean a menses that ends within 15 full days not a menses that starts and ends in a regular time frame, for example each 28 or 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcouse you can pray. Offering salah is religious obligaton for every muslim. A women can take off from salah on respected days of salah just because Allah didnot wanted to burden the body, because only Allah can understand the dificulties of these respected days. but when it comes to any health issue Allah has given ease for offering prayer. one can pray in any way. Allah is the one to accept our prayers and understand our reasonings. :)